# Host multiple projects and services on windows azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms

I have an Ecommerce application built on ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms, I want to migrate the site onto Windows Azure.

> I have 6 projects in my application :
>
> - MyApp.UserWeb    - *My Homepage project
> - MyApp.AdminWeb  - *Administrative web application
> - MyApp.Services - WCF services used by both UserWeb and AdminWeb applications
> - Other 3 are like different layers such as BusinessObjects, DataAccess and Security which are referenced in above 3 projects.

I want to deploy and publish MyApp.UserWeb as www.mysite.com and MyApp.AdminWeb as www.admin.mysite.com and host the services as services.mysite.com

Can you please suggest the steps to deploy and publish the site from Visual studio 2010?

Comment: Eggvertize, Check out this guide for deployment steps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: Don't forget to install the Azure SDK for the additional options needed to deploy to Azure from VS2010: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could publish the three component parts your application to their own web-role. In your DNS settings you can then setup a CNAME record for www, www.admin, and services to point to the respective Virtual IP of each web-role. The CNAMEs will also need to be configured in the Portal for each role.

[Configuring a custom domain name for a Windows Azure cloud service or storage account](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

You may also required multiple instances for the front-end (or other mission critical areas) of your site to guarantee the SLA of 99.95% availability.

The above configuration will give you a decent amount of compute resources for your application and will scale nicely. If you'd prefer to start with a lower cost solution I would suggest running the 3 components on one web-role and adding the 3 CNAMEs.

Azure Websites will be even cheaper again, but this feature is still in preview and has no SLA.

[For step-by-step deployment instructions have a look here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/08/migrating-an-existing-asp-net-app-to-run-on-windows-azure.aspx)

You will also need to [download the Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/):

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with either a Windows Azure Web Site (shared or reserved mode to allow for custom domain names) or a Web Role (Cloud Service).  The choice on a Web Site or Cloud Service varies in what level of control and management you want.

Here is some info on setting up a custom domain name for a Web Site:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/

Comment: I actually wanted the deployment steps as well.. I think I will have to update my question..